# A nonsingular matrix written in the form LU.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

Here is the paragraph from Golan's "Linear Algebra":

> [image]

But I do not understand why U must be nonsingular, could anyone explains this for me please?

Comment: Well, if $A$ is non-singular, then $k=n$. So, $A$, $L$, and $U$ are square matrices. Now, non-singularity is equivalent to the kernel being zero. If $A = LU$, then $\ker U\subset\ker A = \{0\}$ and hence $\ker U = \{0\}$, which means that $U$ is also non-singular. The same, BTW, holds for $L$. You can see that, for example, by transposing everything.

Comment: @amsmath I did not see your comment prior to answering the question. You are correct, you had the same idea and your explanation was more elaborate than mine.

Comment: And why if $A$ is non-singular, $k = n$? Also why non-singularity is equivalent to the kernel being zero?@amsmath

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ were singular then $LU$ were singular as well. 
Note that if there is a non zero vector $v$ such that $Uv=0$ then $LUv=0$ which makes $LU$ singular.

Comment: I wrote exactly this in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is non-singular $\iff A^{-1}= (LU)^{-1} \exists$, but $(LU)^{-1}=U^{-1}L^{-1}$

So, $A$ is non-singular $\iff$ $U^{-1}$ and $L^{-1}$ exist $\iff$ $U$ and $L$ are invertible.